# Mixed compilation of typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to compile typescript code to any target (ES5, ES6 or newer), but with this mixed target features applied simultaneously:

- Template strings should be kept as is.
- Arrow functions should be kept as is.
- `const` and `let` keywords should be compiled into ES5 (`var` and clousure function).

Is it possible and how I should update my `tsconfig`?

Comment: That is...a really unusual combination. I will be surprised bordering on shocked if you can actually do that. Why do you need it?

Comment: @JaredSmith, it's actually a temporary solution. I need the code to access stringified version of arrow functions with template strings inside and some other code is writen with issues so that in case of ES6 browser throws some errors about reading the value before assignment :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible and how I should update my tsconfig?

This is not possible via configuration. With a specific target `es6` you get all these features as is, and with target `es5` they all get transpiled into something ES5 can run.

## More

I cannot think of any JS runtime that would support *template strings as is* but not support *`const` and `let`*.

Comment: That's sad. Upvoted your answer, but want to wait a couple of days before accepting - maybe there is some hack to do that.